Возможно ли управлять консолью через скрипт Python?
Есть задача, которую нужно автоматизировать: при запуске программы нужно вводить несколько команд в терминал на macOS, каждую через определенное время.
Можно ли так сделать на Python? Если есть способ на другом языке, то тоже буду благодарен.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480144/sending-keystrokes-in-applescript-via-automator-in-any-application

Есть такой замечательный модуль, называется Subprocess. Так вот, он позволяет выполнять команды в терминале. Функция для вызова:
subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

Показываю на примере команды clear, которые очищают терминал.
Так вот: записывается команда (тут clear), далее параметр "Shell" должен быть равен "True" (команда выполняется в терминале). И все!
Ну и промежуток между командами задаем через функцию "sleep" модуля "time", который надо импортировать
Если нужны примеры, то идите сюда: https://github.com/KirillMos1/messenger. Там в файле main.py найдете пример.

Надеюсь я Вам помог
